# How to make mutable sequence in Acceleo?

Tags: eclipse, acceleo

So i have a sequence of Visualization Attribute called `vizAttrs`. This is what I actually want to do:

```
[for (va: VisualizationAttribute | dataBinding2.eContents(VisualizationAttribute))]
[vizAttrs = vizAttrs->excluding(va) /]
[/for]
```

If I check the element of `vizAttrs` after the loop, it will still contain the `va` that I expect to be excluded. But if I tried something like:

```
[for (va: VisualizationAttribute | dataBinding2.eContents(VisualizationAttribute))]
[let newVizAttrs:Sequence(VisualizationAttribute) = vizAttrs->excluding(va) /]
[/for]
```

When I check it, the `newVizAttrs` does have the expected value, which excludes that `va` element. But `newVizAttrs` couldn't be used for the next iteration of that for loop. I assumed it's probably because somehow `vizAttrs` is immutable. Is there any way to make `vizAttrs`, or Sequence/Collection, mutable in Acceleo?

Answer (score 0):

I found that apparently all variables in Acceleo are finals. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12003064/12466641

Seems like it is not possible to mutate `vizAttrs` in my case. I will search for a workaround instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you're trying to do, you want to remove all the `VisualizationAttribute` instances contained in `dataBinding2` from `vizAttr`.

You don't need to mutate nothing here, you can just reject them from `vizAttr`.

```
vizAttrs->reject(e | dataBinding2.eContents(VisualizationAttribute)->includes(e))
```